# Hide Edge browser with Selenium in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-edgedriver

I have a question to ask because I am in trouble.
I would like to be able to hide the Browser Edge while running a VBA Routine using Selenium type library.

Using the Chrome browser I can get the result by writing AddArgument "--headless" but with the Edge browser I don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me?

Thanks a lot!  :-)

```
Dim web As New ChromeDriver
    With web
       .AddArgument "--headless"   ''Works with Chrome but doesn't work with Edge
       'OTHER
    End With
```

Comment: IE and Edge do not support the "Headless" mode in Selenium.

Comment: Thanks YasserKhalil! So can you confirm that there is no way to hide the Edge browser with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below code works.
You can find original solution at https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/issues/241 by Maetes

```
Dim brwsr As New EdgeDriver
brwsr.SetCapability "ms:edgeOptions", "{""args"":[""--headless""]}"
```